# What is digram analysis?

Tags: cryptanalysis

so I wanted to ask something since I just learned about cryptography. Here where I have the task to write an essay on cryptography and the title I have to do is introduction digram analysis. However, I did not find any information about digram analysis. What I know is this digram analysis is used on stream and block ciphers. Can anyone explain in more detail what is digram analysis? are Bigram and Digram the same thing? If there is a reference I would appreciate it more. I'm not sure it's digram or diagram analysis.

I hope you guys can explain to me just a little bit so that i understand about this since i didn't find about this.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bigram: Bigram frequency attacks can be used in cryptography to solve cryptograms. See frequency analysis.

Comment: Hello @MaartenBodewes, so what's do you mean is that digram analysis is frequency analysis ?

Comment: Can't think of anything else to be honest. However, frequency analysis is more about classical ciphers than modern block or stream ciphers.